# Script Powershell to list installed updates

Tags: windows, excel, powershell

I'm new here, I am looking for a script for me to list the Windows Updates and then put them on Excel, I have a lot of code that works set apart the display of dates, can you help? Here is the code:

```
$System=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer .

$system=$System.CSName 

$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $True
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

$updateSearcher = new-object -com "Microsoft.Update.Searcher"
$totalupdates = $updateSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$patchList=$updateSearcher.QueryHistory(0,$totalupdates)

write-host "Nombre total de patches installés sur le poste [$system] :" $patchList.Count
write-host "Préparation du classeur Excel...."

$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Sheet.Name = "Patches installés"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Titre"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "Description"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,3) = "Date"

$Sheet.activate()

$Sheet.application.activewindow.splitrow = 1
$Sheet.application.activewindow.freezepanes = $true

$intRow = 2

$WorkBook = $Sheet.UsedRange

$WorkBook.Interior.ColorIndex = 11
$WorkBook.Font.ColorIndex = 19
$WorkBook.Font.Bold = $True

Foreach($patch in $patchList){

$HotfixID=$patch.Title
$HotfixID=$HotfixID.Split('(')
$HotfixID=$HotfixID[1]
$HotfixID=$HotfixID.Trim(')')

$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $HotfixID
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $patch.Title
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 3) = $patch.Installeddate

$intRow = $intRow + 1}
```

Comment: Do you not just require `$patch.Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information with `$patch.Date` within the foreach loop